# include/require once in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Could you please tell me which one (include or require once) is it better to use. As I have read require_once is preffered as it stops the execution after an error. It depends of what you want to include, right? Also using include and require makes the code to be more effective? As I can understand the incude and require just make the code more clear(helping to avoid repeating parts of code), effectiveness is not achieved as the same code is added in each file. Finally, I have some javascript code in each of my files(different javascript code in each file) Is it a good idea to put all the javascript code from all of my pages into one file and just include this file in each page? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please break your question into smaller multiple questions and post them separately.

Comment: ok! Sorry for that! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your JS questions, do separate questions.

It's simple for me:

**include_once**

Only use if your script will continue without the included script, without errors or odd behaviors (rare).

**require_once**

Use if your script needs the required file, such as database connection details or anything of the sort.

If your error_level is set appropriately this shouldn't pose a problem/issue.

Comment: I prefer to use `require_one` in cause that usually there is not cases when I do not need to included script. Also when included script can not be added it is an error and should be handled in different way as using of `include_once`.